# How to display notes in opportunity form of mscrm 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I need to display account notes across all opportunities. typically a MSCRM creates a blank Notes section for each new Opportunity you create inside a account, but I need to display a running Account dialog of conversations to review in one continues notepad (means display all notes).

Can anyone tell me how I can display all notes in the opportunity form?

Is this possible without coding (or in fact, with coding!)

Thanks in advance,

SD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do this a few different ways.

1) The easiest way is to add an IFRAME and then point to the applicable Account notes container.  You'd have to set the "id" attribute based on the account.  Here's what your IFRAME url will look like:

```
/_controls/notes/notesdata.aspx?EnableInlineEdit=true&EnableInsert=true&id=%7bEF88BCAA-C3EB-E111-B142-78E7D162EE67%7d&ParentEntity=1
```

2) If you are only wanting to display the notes and not allow for a user to edit them (read-only), then you'll need to use fetch to query the annotations where the related id equals the account.

Comment: I have set below URL to disable user to edit the notes in MS CRM 2011 but it still show editable notes to user. can you tell me what is going wrong with my code.   IFrame.setSrc("/_controls/notes/notesdata.aspx?id="+ accountid + " &ParentEntity=1&EnableInlineEdit=false&EnableInsert=false");

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear the on requirement here.

I believe you are saying: Each Account has multiple Opportunities, each Opportunity has many Notes. On the Account you want to show all the Notes for all the Opportunities.

I don't think you can achieve this with out of the box functionaility, I would suggest creating an SSRS report and iFrame'ing it in.